# Increase audio volume for Twilio say command

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Does anybody know a way to increase the audio volume (loudness) of the `<Say>` verb command on Twilio?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such option, is probably expected for this to be controlled on the receiving side.

You can experiment with the value of the *"voice"* attribute *(man, woman, alice)* and see (hear) which one sounds better for your case. Often a clearer voice will make it up for loudness.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say